# VAR, test for normality, autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity- should I use stationary first differences for these tests?

Tags: econometrics, heteroscedasticity, vector-autoregression

I am checking thhe long-term relationship between unemployment  and labor force participation rate. I have a integration order I(1) and I want to run VAR.  As far as I understand I need to use first differences in VAR cause they are stationary. Should I perform tests for heteroskedasticity, normality and autocorrelation on them or variables on levels?

Answer (score 0):

Testing for heteroskedasticity, normality and autocorrelation is done on **residuals**.  They are applied retrospectively to the finished estimate model (in first differences).  Note that normality is not needed for a consistent irf -> [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285158/is-normality-of-residuals-necessary-for-drawing-conclusions-from-impulse-respons)